# How do I make Excel NOT convert the dates to date format

Tags: excel, csv, date

I did this table in Excel, but this is really frustrating: in certain cells, unpredictable to me, it doesn't let me just write `01/03/2019`. Instead, it automaticly transforms it to `1/3/19`. To be honest, I don't mind the first part; the real issue is that I need it to be `2019`, and not `19`, since I'm saving it in `.csv` format and not keeping it in `.xlsx`.

Therefore, what I need is a way to make Excel maintain exactly what I wrote without transforming it in `Date` format (changing it to `General` just gives that format with the number of days since 1900, `43468`), or at least, I need the year to stay as `2019`.

This is the colum with the dates:

```
1
19/05/2009
2
19/05/2010
3
19/05/2011
4
19/05/2012
5
19/05/2013
6
19/05/2014
7
19/05/2015
8
19/05/2016
9
19/11/2016
10
16/11/2018
11
20/12/2018
12
"01/03/2019"
13
17/7/2019
14
"12/09/2019"
15
30/10/2019
16
"12/12/2019"
17
"11/1/2020"
18
19/02/2020
19
20/04/2020
20
17/05/2020
21
13/06/2020
22
"02/07/2020"
23
13/08/2020
24
13/09/2020
25
15/10/2020
26
15/11/2020
27
19/09/2009
28
19/01/2010
29
19/09/2010
30
19/11/2010
31
19/03/2011
32
19/05/2011
33
19/09/2011
34
19/05/2012
35
19/09/2012
36
19/05/2013
37
19/10/2013
38
19/05/2014
39
19/05/2015"
40
19/05/2016
41
19/11/2016
42
19/01/2019
43
19/08/2020
44
19/10/2008
45
19/01/2009
46
19/04/2009
47
19/07/2009
```

I temporariyl put in quotation marks (") as placeholders, because they keep the text to be converted to `Date`, but I don't want to keep them.

Comment: Change the format to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: It already is.... At least, that's how I meant it...

Comment: Oh, that's why... It's the ones that can be interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy by Excel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on a comment from @BigBen, I got it: I selected the cells and did `Format Cells` (Format > Cells **or** Right Click and it's almost at the bottom **or** `Cmd + 1`. Then I wen to `Date` and selected the format `3/14/2012` instead of `*3/14/12`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a ' (quote) string before anything and it gets displayed as a string.

Comment: I know it does; that's why I put it. WHat I want is to NOT put anything and just have the date there.